# Fastest way to find if a number is in range

Tags: c, performance, image-processing, optimization

I try to write a piece of code that takes a square image and apply a sharpen kernel.

I did manage to succeed in my task but I was disappointed by the running times of my program. The time it takes to blur an image and sharpen it (500x500) takes about 16 ms, I want to go lower than that, I used `callgrind` and `cachegrind` and I do see my cache miss is pretty low (About 3%) so as I tried to narrow down the problem I notices that every time I apply the kernel on a pixel I ask the follow if any of the channels is in range of [0,255]. I would like to know if there is a fast way to calculate if number is in range so far I use the following macros:

```
#define max(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
#define min(a, b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

My pixel struct:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char red;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char blue;
} pixel;
```

and my calculation:

```
//p is a struct of pixel.
p.red = min(max(sumRed, 0), 255);
p.green = min(max(sumGreen, 0), 255);
p.blue = min(max(sumBlue, 0), 255);
```

Comment: What is the value range of `sumRed` and what is its type?

Comment: why do you need to ask if the values are in the range 0-255? if this is an image of 8bit it supposed to be a given not?

Comment: What do you hope to achieve with `max(sumRed, 0)`? These are `unsigned` values.

Comment: sumRed is an integer , which is the sum of the pixel's red values , It is my first time doing something like this , as I read I need to apply the kernel on a pixel , took my info from here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)

Comment: values after applying the kernel can be negative , because the kernel is { {-1, -1 , -1} {-1, 9,-1}{-1, -1,-1}} so lets say after applying the kernel i got a negative value i want to put a zero becuase such pixel value doesnt exist.

Comment: If somebody can point out what am i missing here , why shouldn't i care about the pixel RGB possible negative value after applying the kernel

Comment: You clearly stated `unsigned char red;` so the only way that sums of red can be negative, is if you summed them to a `signed char`. Otherwise, if you are summing a huge numbers of pixels, their sum could overflow `int`.

Comment: my sumRed, sumBlue,sumGreen are integers, should i change it in my code to unsigned char ? I dont see the logic behind it.

Comment: No do not change the sum to a char type. Your question is unclear: how can pixels' sum be in range of unsigned char?

Comment: My point is that after applying the kernel , sumRed, sumGreen,sumBlue can have the following values :
negative - then i put the correct RGB value to 0, a value that is above 255 - than i put a 255 , and a value that is in the range of [0,255] which is ok and i dont change it's value
I can the negative value from applying the kernel i mentioned above , or a very big positive value if the pixel around the pixel i am applying the kernel on have a low RGB value and the pixel that is multiplyed by 9 has high RGB values.

Comment: @WeatherVane: It's a convolution sum, the values are scaled by signed coefficients before being added together.  So even though the input is strictly non-negative, the result of the convolution may be negative.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave#/media/File:Fourier_series_for_square_wave.gif where the square wave never goes outside [-1:1] but the filtered versions do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually looking for a fast way to clamp values within a given range.

If you know the maximum range the values can take, which can probably be determined from the algorithm used, you can use a lookup table with an offset:

```
// clamp_table is a table of unsigned char of size maxvalue - minvalue + 1
// initialized this way:
unsigned char clamp_table[maxvalue - minvalue + 1];
for (size_t i = minvalue; i < 0; i++) {
    clamp_table[i - minvalue] = 0;
}
for (size_t i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    clamp_table[i - minvalue] = i;
}
for (size_t i = 256; i <= maxvalue; i++) {
    clamp_table[i - minvalue] = 255;
}

// clamping becomes a simple table indirection:
r.red = clamp_table[sumRed - minvalue];
r.green = clamp_table[sumGreen - minvalue];
r.blue = clamp_table[sumBlue - minvalue];
```

`minvalue` and `maxvalue` should be known at compile time, `clamp_table` can then be made a statically initialized const array for improved performance.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I did improve my running time , now I stand on 5 ms !

Comment: You could ask a separate question with the complete code for your filters on http://codereview.stackoverflow.com asking for potential improvements. Filters can be tweaked dramatically, for example using vector intrinsics.